# Who is the commentator on Yogasutras Swami Vivekananda talking about?

Tags: vivekananda, yoga-sutras

While reading Raja Yoga by Swami Vivekananda, I found that he is talking about commentator.

[CHAPTER I
CONCENTRATION: ITS SPIRITUAL USES](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/raja-yoga/concentration_its_spiritual_uses.htm):

On the 27<sup>th</sup> Sutra:

> तस्य वाचकः प्रणवः ॥२७॥
>
> 27. His manifesting word is Om.
>
> . . . . . **Our commentator says**, "Although the relation between thought and word is perfectly natural, yet it does not mean a rigid connection between one sound and one idea." These sounds vary, yet the relation between the sounds and the thoughts is a natural one. The connection between thoughts and sounds is good only if there be a real connection between the thing signified and the symbol; until then that symbol will never come into general use. A symbol is the manifester of the thing signified, and if the thing signified has already an existence, and if, by experience, we know that the symbol has expressed that thing many times, then we are sure that there is a real relation between them. Even if the things are not present, there will be thousands who will know them by their symbols. There must be a natural connection between the symbol and the thing signified; then, when that symbol is pronounced, it recalls the thing signified. **The commentator says** the manifesting word of God is Om. . . . .

I know about two commentators Vyasa and Vijnanabhikshu.

So, who is the commentator of YogaSutras Swami Vivekananda is talking about in his work Raja Yoga?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swami Vivekananda only consulted Vyasa Bhashya and not any other Bhashyas while writing his own on Patanjali Yoga Sutras. Vyasa Bhasya is referred to in the Raja Yoga book at many places.

So, Vijyana Bhikshu is ruled out from the start.

Now, Vachaspati Mishra also has written a commentary on that Vyasa Bhasya. So, by *tikAkAra* (commentator) he either means Vyasa himself or Vachaspati Mishra.

This confusion is cleared when I find the commentary by Vachaspati Mishra (on Vyasa's commentary on Yoga Sutras 1.27) is given in the footnote of the Raja Yoga that I have.

The footnote says (in Bengali) -

> Vyasa Bhasyer Vachaspati Mishra katrik Tika ( i.e Vachaspati Mishra's
>   commentary on Vyasa Bhasya)

The following commentary by Vachaspati Mishra (on Vyasa's Bhasya on 1.27) Swami Vivekananda quotes while explaining 1.27:

> Sarve eva shabdAh sarvAkArArthAbhidhAnasamarthA ---- Iti stitha
>   evaishAm sarvAkArairarthiah swAbhAvikah sambandah |
>
> Our commentator says “Although the relation between thought and word
>   is perfectly natural, yet it does not mean a rigid connection between
>   one sound and one idea.”

So, here by "commentator" he refers to Vachaspati Mishra and not Vyasa.

Comment: Can you provide translation for the quote. Thanks

Comment: This portion is Vachaspati Mishra's Tika on Vyasa's Tika on Yoga Sutras 1.27. Sanskrit is given in the footnote of the Raja Yoga book. So, it is Mishra and not Vyasa. @Pandya

Comment: So, you find it from foot-note in the Raja Yoga book you've? ok. Got it! Can you attach the screen-shot? Thanks

Comment: What's the use of attaching it here as it is in Bengali letters. @Pandya